# Public static variables

Tags: c#

I'm using a public static variable in C# Windows forms application. I have two files as `Audits.cs` and `Findings.cs`. I have created a public static variable as F_Status in `Audits.cs` file and made it to assign to the value '1' when an item is selected in a `listView`. I'm going to use this variable in `Findings.cs` file in an if statement. My coding in the `Findings.cs` file is as follows.

```
if (Audits.F_Status==1)
{
   // Do something
}
```

I have made some break points and tested the coding. In `Audits.cs` file the variable get assigned to the value '1' and however when it come to the if statement in `Findings.cs` file the value of the F_Status become '0'. I cannot understand why? If anyone can help me it will be great.

Comment: May be somewhere it is set to `0` again?

Comment: Please add the code for the relevant parts of Findings, especially showing when the value is set.

Comment: Despite you seem to have debugged into it, is it possible that the statement in `Findings.cs` is executed before the assignment in `Audits.cs`?

Comment: I haven't use this variable anywhere else other than these two places.

Comment: "I'm using a public static variable". Well, don't. Find a way to code this properly. A public static variable is always a sign that your architecture is broken. You will not be able to unit test this properly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the value is set somewhere else. To find out where this happens, implement the variable as property and set a break-point on it. Of course, don't use an auto property as this wont hit the break point

Comment: Or alternatively, automatically search all references to the variable in the project (which, however, would not cover access via reflection).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you set F_Status = 1 inside a handler for event ListView.ItemSelectionChanged. ListView raises the event multiple times when the selected item changes: probably the last of these indicates *unselected* for the previously selected item.

MSDN's reference [ListView.ItemSelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) includes example code to debug the event behaviour. But the example calls MessageBox.Show which to me defeats the purpose of analyzing an event's behaviour - when it's a window event. I'd add at the top of the file:

`using System.Diagnostics;`

And inside the event handler add appropriate calls to Trace.WriteLine, to see how the value of IsSelected changes.

As a commenter noted, there are better designs for telling form B that an item on form A's ListView is selected. The public static variable in form A is undesirable because form B can change the value, which is probably not what you want, and often leads to disaster. There are lots of examples on the web for designing interaction between forms - using a [structured programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) approach.